# Modified files in externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have a sandbox, which has directories in the repository intermingled with directories directly from the repository.  `svn status --ignore-externals` will tell me the status of the files that are in the repository.  What is a good way to do the opposite?

If, for example, I have

```
$ svn status
X foo
M bar/local.cpp

Performing status on external item at 'foo'
M foo/external.cpp
```

so that, ignoring external, I have

```
$ svn status --ignore-externals
X foo
M bar/local.cpp
```

I am looking for something like

```
$ svn status --ignore-local
X foo

Performing status on external item at 'foo'
M foo/external.cpp
```

where only the files that are in the external repository are listed.

This will probably end up in a shell or Perl script, so something fairly complicated is acceptable.

I know that I can do `svn status foo`, but my actual case has about a dozen externals, and the number is slowly growing over time.  Hard-coding a list is not a good solution.

It looks like I might be able to just look for the string `Performing status` and ignore everything before it.  (I don't care about the `X` lines.)  Is that ordering something I can rely on?

**Edit**: To clarify, I am looking for files from the external repository which have been modified in my sandbox.  I do not care if the file has also been modified in the external repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. "...look for the string Performing status..." give you **nothing** useful in the case of pure `svn st`
2. You have to read about `-u` option of `svn status` command and about `svn propget` command in order to operate on mutable list of externals in your code

Samples in Working Copy (for HEAD-type externals) with externals, updated in repo plus local modifications in WC

## Pure status

```
trunk>svn st
?       Core\core+.txt
M       Core\core.txt
X       Extensions\Mod1
X       Extensions\Mod2

Performing status on external item at 'Extensions\Mod1':

Performing status on external item at 'Extensions\Mod2':
```

There **are** changes for 'Extensions\Mod*` in repository, but you miss it

## Status with checking repo

```
trunk>svn st -u
?                    Core\core+.txt
M                4   Core\core.txt
X                    Extensions\Mod1
X                    Extensions\Mod2
Status against revision:      5

Performing status on external item at 'Extensions\Mod1':
        *            Extensions\Mod1\file3.txt
        *        4   Extensions\Mod1
Status against revision:      5

Performing status on external item at 'Extensions\Mod2':
        *        4   Extensions\Mod2\file1.txt
Status against revision:      5
```

## Getting all externals

Rather complex case: two different mount points,  a set of externals in one point

```
WC>svn pg svn:externals -R
trunk\Core - ^/Vendor/Core+ Core+

trunk\Extensions - ^/Vendor/Lib1 Mod1
^/Vendor/Lib2 Mod2
^/Vendor/Lib3 Mod3
```

In order to avoid "noisy" output (as it will be for 'Externsions\' node - lines with leading X)

```
WC>svn st -u trunk/Extensions

    Status against revision:      7
    X                    trunk\Extensions\Mod1
    X                    trunk\Extensions\Mod2
    Status against revision:      7

    Performing status on external item at 'trunk\Extensions\Mod1':
            *            trunk\Extensions\Mod1\file3.txt
            *        4   trunk\Extensions\Mod1
    Status against revision:      7

    Performing status on external item at 'trunk\Extensions\Mod2':
            *        4   trunk\Extensions\Mod2\file1.txt
    Status against revision:      7
```

you have to request status of only directly externals dir, full path to which you have to combine from `pg` output, f.e (**`trunk\Extensions`** - ^/Vendor/Lib1 **`Mod1`**)

```
>svn st -u trunk\Extensions\Mod1
        *            trunk\Extensions\Mod1\file3.txt
        *        4   trunk\Extensions\Mod1
Status against revision:      8
```

and any output before "Status against revision" means existing repository-side changes: for not touched externals output will be

```
>svn st -u trunk\Extensions\Mod3
Status against revision:      8
```

Comment: The -u flag is not useful to me: I care about changes in the sandbox, not the repository.  It looks like what I want is `svn status | something_to_parse_and_combine_output.pl | xargs svn status`

Comment: @TroyDaniels - Okay, u wanna to read starting from "Getting all externals"